# Monitoring ASP.net pages CPU usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, cpu-usage, debug-diagnostic-tool

I'm having some performance issues with a web application. The CPU usage of this application pool can exceed the 90%. The normal usage I noticed is 30%.

I used Debug Diagnostic tool to monitor the CPU usage of this application and I figured out that SNIReadSyncOverAsync is the problem. I don't have any other details about which function on my application or page is behind the call to SNIReadSyncOverAsync. What I need to know is which page are consuming the most CPU in my application.

Do you have any idea how can I monitor each page performance ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use perfmon(performance monitor). you can invoke it from Start -> Run -> Perfmon.exe. 
you can setup the counters and see on using which page there is a spike. for more details refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645516(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have any idea how can I monitor each page performance ?

Yes there is a way to see what is consuming the CPU in a production environment by using the **Windows Performance Recorder**. For example,

On the server in question run the commands below at the prompt

```
wpr -start DotNET
```

When the code in question has executed, run

```
wpr -stop DotNET
```

Then using the **Windows Performance Analyzer**, you can analyze the ETL file created by WPR. See Microsoft's Channel9 for details.

Alternatively, you can also use **PerfView** to capture requests that take longer than expected.  For example,

```
perfview collect -StopOnRequestOverMsec:3000 -ThreadTime -Merge:true -Zip:true -LogFile:perfviewlog.log -CircularMB:512 -DataFile:LongRequest.etl
```

Then analyze the stack information using PerfView.